# Arquillian tests fail on JBoss eap 6.1 (but working on JBoss 7.1.1)

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-arquillian, jboss-eap-6

I have a problem running my arquillian tests (started by a jenkins job) on a JBoss eap 6.1 server. It's no problem to run the tests on a JBoss 7.1.1 server, but when I switch to the eap 6.1 I get the following exception for all tests:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching test at http://0.0.0.0:8080/test/ArquillianServletRunner?outputMode=serializedObject&className=testClass&methodName=testMethod&cmd=event. Got 503 (Service Unavailable)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.execute(ServletMethodExecutor.java:214)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor$1.run(ServletMethodExecutor.java:243)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

If I run the tests on a EAP 6.1 server on my local machine everything works fine (it's the same configuration so that can't be a problem).

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

arquillian dependencies:

> ```
>       <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
>             <artifactId>jboss-javaee6-specs-bom</artifactId>
>             <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
>             <type>pom</type>
>             <scope>test</scope>
>         </dependency>
>        <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
>             <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
>             <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
>             <scope>test</scope>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
>             <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
>             <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
>             <scope>test</scope>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
>             <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
>             <version>${version.org.jboss.jbossas}</version>
>             <scope>test</scope>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
>             <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
>             <version>${version.org.jboss.jbossas}</version>
>             <scope>test</scope>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
>             <artifactId>arquillian-persistence-impl</artifactId>
>             <version>1.0.0.Alpha5</version>
>             <scope>test</scope>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
>             <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
>             <version>2.0.0</version>
>             <scope>test</scope>
>             <type>pom</type>
>         </dependency>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
>             <artifactId>shrinkwrap-api</artifactId>
>             <version>1.2.0</version>
>         </dependency>
> ```

Comment: for your jboss container dependency, are you using 7.2.0 or 7.1.1?  Also, can you get any logs off of the remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that removing`<defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0"/>` from arquillian.xml would fix this problem.