# Jenkins "__redirected.__SAXParserFactory not found" on JBoss eap 6.1

Tags: jboss, jenkins, jboss-eap-6

I have the problem that I get the following exception after my my tests ran on an eap 6.1 server (using arquillian) started by jenkins. On my local machine everything works fine so I think it must be a jenkins related problem.

Jenkins Version is 1.530, maven  version is 3.0.4

```
Results :

Tests run: 98, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[JENKINS] Recording test results
Warning: Caught exception attempting to use SAX to load a SAX XMLReader 
Warning: Exception was: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
Warning: I will print the stack trace then carry on using the default SAX parser
org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(XMLReaderFactory.java:229)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(XMLReaderFactory.java:190)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXHelper.createXMLReader(SAXHelper.java:83)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.createXMLReader(SAXReader.java:894)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.getXMLReader(SAXReader.java:715)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:435)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:264)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.SuiteResult.parse(SuiteResult.java:130)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:274)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parsePossiblyEmpty(TestResult.java:230)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:199)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.SurefireArchiver.postExecute(SurefireArchiver.java:148)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.recordMojoEnded(Maven3Builder.java:622)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.mojoSucceeded(Maven3Builder.java:604)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:228)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:130)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:67)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.NewInstance.newInstance(NewInstance.java:82)
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(XMLReaderFactory.java:227)
    ... 47 more
```

...

```
INFO: 
Sep 11, 2013 3:31:14 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger mojoStarted
INFO: --- maven-site-plugin:3.2:site (default-site) @ bp-ejb ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.4
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.2
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.0.1
[INFO] Parent project loaded from repository: de.msg.iss:iss-parent-pom:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] No project URL defined - decoration links will not be relativized!
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.4
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:130)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:67)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider __redirected.__SAXParserFactory not found
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getFactory(Digester.java:500)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getParser(Digester.java:714)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:944)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1765)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.XmlFactoryConfiguration.read(XmlFactoryConfiguration.java:128)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.FileFactoryConfiguration.read(FileFactoryConfiguration.java:140)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.FileFactoryConfiguration.read(FileFactoryConfiguration.java:116)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.FileFactoryConfiguration.read(FileFactoryConfiguration.java:91)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.FileFactoryConfiguration.read(FileFactoryConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.FileFactoryConfiguration.read(FileFactoryConfiguration.java:59)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.ConfigurationUtils.getDefaultTools(ConfigurationUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.ConfigurationUtils.getAutoLoaded(ConfigurationUtils.java:176)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.ToolManager.autoConfigure(ToolManager.java:74)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.ToolManager.<init>(ToolManager.java:68)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.ToolManager.<init>(ToolManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.createVelocityContext(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:430)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.generateDocument(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.renderLocale(SiteMojo.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:117)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: __redirected/__SAXParserFactory
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(FactoryFinder.java:123)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:178)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:147)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:219)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:126)
    ... 55 more
channel stopped
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.util.IOException2
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:183)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:67)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:130)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:181)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:178)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider __redirected.__SAXParserFactory not found
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getFactory(Digester.java:500)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getParser(Digester.java:714)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:944)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1765)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.XmlFactoryConfiguration.read(XmlFactoryConfiguration.java:128)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.FileFactoryConfiguration.read(FileFactoryConfiguration.java:140)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.FileFactoryConfiguration.read(FileFactoryConfiguration.java:116)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.FileFactoryConfiguration.read(FileFactoryConfiguration.java:91)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.FileFactoryConfiguration.read(FileFactoryConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.FileFactoryConfiguration.read(FileFactoryConfiguration.java:59)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.ConfigurationUtils.getDefaultTools(ConfigurationUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.config.ConfigurationUtils.getAutoLoaded(ConfigurationUtils.java:176)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.ToolManager.autoConfigure(ToolManager.java:74)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.ToolManager.<init>(ToolManager.java:68)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.ToolManager.<init>(ToolManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.createVelocityContext(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:430)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.generateDocument(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.renderLocale(SiteMojo.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:117)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: __redirected/__SAXParserFactory
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(FactoryFinder.java:123)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:178)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:147)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:219)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:126)
    ... 55 more
[ANALYSIS-COLLECTOR] Skipping publisher since build result is FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing
`<forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>60</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
<forkMode>never</forkMode>` from maven-surefire-plugin fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a XML parser classloading issue. This could come from a variety of reasons (non standard JBoss installation, e.g. override of the xml parser using command line arguments), messing with bootstrap libraries, just plain incompatibility because of difference in how that particular jboss classloading is implemented.

I would recommend you to:

- check that your jboss installation is standard (maybe try with the original jboss 6.1 on a fresh machine)
- search for troubleshooting tips on Jenkins Jira, e.g. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10238
- contact the jenkins-user mailing list or open an issue in Jira

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I already tried a fresh jboss installation and looked into the jenkins jira. The next step I wanted to do is open an issue, but first I wanted to ask here, maybe someone experienced something like that. ;)

Comment: when you said on your local machine everything worked fine, that was with the same jboss installation ? If so check if there are some differences in either the installed libraries and configuration in your jboss installation directory

Comment: It's exactly the same configuration because it's checked out from svn. I also have another problem with EAP 6.1 on my local machine and the server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693376/arquillian-tests-fail-on-jboss-eap-6-1-but-working-on-jboss-7-1-1 ... I don't know what could be the problem because it's all the same ...