# Arquillian : error while trying to deploy WAR

Tags: junit, jboss, war, junit4, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to implement unit tests for REST WS and I am using Arquillian to do this but the problem is that the deployment failed every time even when I use the WAR deployed successfully on the server JBOSS.

Test Class:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class CalendrierCommissionServiceTest {

@Inject
private CalendrierCommissionService calenderCommissionService;


@Deployment
public static Archive<WebArchive> createTestArchive() {
    return ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(WebArchive.class, new File("target/myWar-SNAPSHOT.war"));
}

// Tests findByIdCommission
@Test
public void testFindByIdCommission_shouldNotFindWithZero(){
    assertThat(calenderCommissionService.findByIdCommission(BigInteger.ZERO)).isEmpty();
}
}
```

Here the log error :

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Cannot deploy: mywar-SNAPSHOT.war
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:83)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:64)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:46)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.deploy(CommonDeployableContainer.java:144)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:161)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:128)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:127)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:95)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:80)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:263)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:239)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:101)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:182)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Invalid type character 'S'
at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.readExternal(ModelNode.java:1538)
at org.jboss.dmr.ObjectModelValue.<init>(ObjectModelValue.java:62)
at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.readExternal(ModelNode.java:1531)
at org.jboss.dmr.ObjectModelValue.<init>(ObjectModelValue.java:62)
at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.readExternal(ModelNode.java:1531)
at org.jboss.dmr.ObjectModelValue.<init>(ObjectModelValue.java:62)
at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.readExternal(ModelNode.java:1531)
at org.jboss.dmr.ObjectModelValue.<init>(ObjectModelValue.java:62)
at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.readExternal(ModelNode.java:1531)
at org.jboss.dmr.ObjectModelValue.<init>(ObjectModelValue.java:62)
at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.readExternal(ModelNode.java:1531)
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient$1.handleRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:169)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:244)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler.handleRequest(AbstractMessageHandler.java:209)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:112)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementClientChannelStrategy$Establishing$1.handleMessage(ManagementClientChannelStrategy.java:148)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelReceiver.handleMessage(ManagementChannelReceiver.java:80)
at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel$5.run(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:437)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Have you any idea about the problem please ?

Comment: Can you provide some more info? For example the test class?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Are you sure that WAR is built at the time of test execution? If that's the case you can inspect content of the deployed archive using following configuration in your `arquillian.xml`:  https://gist.github.com/bartoszmajsak/ff84f207a926bc76470d7a645904f720

Answer (score 0):

for me it solved by using this in pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-spi</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

from here: [Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049175/could-not-create-new-instance-of-class-org-jboss-arquillian-test-impl-eventtestr)

cheers!